# Error paginando resultados de MySQL en PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, paginación

Estoy paginando resultados de una consulta hecha a MySQL desde PHP con PDO. El caso es que me devuelve los resultados paginas, pero no siempre.

```
function listar(){
        if (isset($_GET["criterio"])){ 
                $txt_criterio = $_GET["criterio"];
                $criterio = "WHERE acronimo_ins LIKE '%$txt_criterio%'";

                //Limito la busqueda 
                $TAMANO_PAGINA = 2; 

                //examino la página a mostrar y el inicio del registro a mostrar 
                $pagina = 1;
                $inicio = 0;
                if(isset($_GET["pagina"])){
                    (int)$pagina = $_GET["pagina"];
                    $inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $TAMANO_PAGINA;
                }
        $ssql = "SELECT * FROM sedes ".$criterio;
                try{
                    $rs = $pdo->prepare($ssql);
                    $rs->execute();
                    $num_total_registros = $rs->rowCount();

                    //calculo el total de páginas 
                    $total_paginas = ceil($num_total_registros / $TAMANO_PAGINA); 
                    //pongo el número de registros total, el tamaño de página y la página que se muestra 
                    $formod .= "<p>Número de registros encontrados: " . $num_total_registros . "</p>"; 
                    $formod .= "<p>Se muestran páginas de " . $TAMANO_PAGINA . " registros cada una</p>"; 
                    $formod .= "<p>Mostrando la página " . $pagina . " de " . $total_paginas . "</p>";
    if ($total_paginas > 1){ 
                    for ($i=1;$i<=$total_paginas;$i++){ 
                        if ($pagina == $i){
                          //si muestro el índice de la página actual, no coloco enlace 
                          $formod .= '<a href="#" title="Página actual: '.$pagina.'">'.$pagina . "</a>"; 
                        }else {
                          //si el índice no corresponde con la página mostrada actualmente, coloco el enlace para ir a esa página 
                          $formod .= '<a title="Ir a página: '.$i.'" href="?pagina=' . $i . '&criterio=' . $txt_criterio . '">' . $i . '</a> '; 
                        }
                    }
                }
     }catch(PDOException $error){
                $formod = 'Error de conexión: ' . $error;
                $formod .= "Se ha producido un error y no se han podido bajar los datos de la BD.";
            }
     try{
                //construyo la sentencia SQL 
                $ssqsl = "SELECT * FROM sedes " . $criterio." limit " .$inicio."," .$TAMANO_PAGINA;
                $rs = $pdo->prepare($ssqsl);

                $rs->execute();
    $formod.='<table>';
    while ($fila = $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    foreach($fila as $row){
                        $formod .= '<tr class="table-body-element">
                        <td class="table-body-element"><p>'.$row['id_ins'].'/'.$row['id_sede'].'</p></td>
                        <td class="table-body-element">'.$row['id_ins'].'</td>
                        <td class="table-body-element">'.$row['acronimo_ins'].'</td>
                        <td class="table-body-element">'.$row['id_sede'].'</td> 
                        <td class="table-body-element">'.$row['nombre_corto'].'</td> 
                        <td class="table-body-element">'.$row['provincia'].'</td> 
                        <td class="table-body-element">'.$row['localidad'].'</td> 
                        <td class="table-body-element">'.$row['direccion']." ".$row['cpzip'].'</td> 
                        <td class="table-body-element">'.$row['estado_sede'].'</td> 
                        <td class="table-body-element">'.$row['fecha_est_sede'].'</td></tr>';
                    }
                }

            }catch(PDOException $error){
                $formods = 'Error de conexión: ' . $error;
                $formods .= "Se ha producido un error y no se han podido bajar los datos de la BD.";
                return $formods;
            }

        }
        $formod .= '</table>';
        return $formod;
}
```

El problema que me surge es que, haciendo todo bien, hay páginas que me funcionan y otras que no.

Cuando la variable  `$TAMANO_PAGINA = 2;` está en dos y hay solo 10 resultados en la base de datos, las páginas 4 y 5 cargan, pero no muestran nada.

Lo mismo pasa con otros tamaños, por ejemplo: `$TAMANO_PAGINA = 3;` la página 3 no carga, pero la 4 si muestra 1 resultado.

**EDITO**

Me he dado cuenta de que la consulta funciona bien, pero solo contienen resultados y cargan la tabla la primera mitad de las páginas, la segunda mitad carga sin errores, pero no muestra la tabla. Como ejemplo, si tengo 4 páginas con resultados la 1 y la 2 muestran los resultados correctamente, pero la 3 y la 4 no muestran resultado alguno, ni tabla ni enlaces, sin lanzar un error de ningún tipo, la web carga, no muestra error pero no hay resultados. Siempre me pasa con la mitad de las páginas. Si tengo 5 las 3 primeras cargan y las 2 últimas no, así con todos.

¿Alguna idea de por qué pasa esto?.

Comment: Utilizas Javascript? porque si es así, puedes usar el [datatable](https://datatables.net/), solo debes regresar un JSON al JS y automáticamente te crea la tabla, te deje el enlace para que veas la documentación

Comment: Gracias por tu interés. No, no utilizo Javascript. Esto es parte de un código que le envío a un Drupal 8. Pese a que hay formas concretas de trabajar con Drupal 8, como ya explican en sus tutoriales, yo estoy saltandome un poco las formas de Drupal y haciéndolo como necesito, esto es parte de un código con 30 funciones, que drupal carga en función de lo que el admin busque.

Answer (score 1):

Después de mucho pelearme con el código saqué los registros de uno en uno y fui viendo en cuales me daba el error y en cuales no. Mas tarde comparé estos registros para ver que tenían en común.

Lo único que tenían en común era que la codificación no estaba bien. En la base de datos aparecía una ñ pero en la página web no aparecía nada porque Drupal lo bloqueaba, dado que era un carácter extraño.

La solución fue añadir charset=utf8 al dsn de PDO.

```
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$dbnames;host=$host;charset=utf8";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
```

Y ahora sube los caracteres correctamente y los recupera igual. Lo dejo aquí como dato, por si alguien esta haciendo algo similar y le sirve.